# IIS6 Virtual directory not using assigned folder

Tags: iis-6

I have an IIS 6 instance with a web site that has a few virtual directories. One of those was re-assigned to a new path but the webserver still serves from the old path.

I've restarted IIS. Is there some other setting that might cause IIS to hold on to the old reference?

Comment: I notice in the metabase that there are two IIsWebVirtualDir entries for this virtual dir.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix by editing the metabase.xml file to remove the old virtual directory entry:

1. Stop IIS
2. Edit metabase.xml
3. Start IIS